# Which angular tilt package to use with Angular 15?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angularjs-directive

I have found that `@geometricpanda/angular-tilt@0.3.0` is not compaitble with `Angular 15`.

Which angular tilt package to use with Angular 15?

Comment: I would advise against using a package that is downloaded 65 times per week.

Comment: can you suggest any other package which can be used for tilt functionality?